# .net core 2.1 + Angular 6 + http.post does not reach controller

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, http-post

I am having an issue with the http.post method in Angular 6, not reaching my controller. The http.get works fine. There is no error seen in the client browser diagnostics network tab.

Angular service code:

```
saveResponse(response: Response): Observable<any> {
const body = JSON.stringify(response);
return this.http.post(this.postResponseUrl, body, httpOptions)
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
```

}

When I debug the "this.postResponseUrl", it shows "http://localhost:xxxx/api/surveyresponses" , which should be correct.

Controller in ASP.NET api

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using survey.Data;
using survey.Interfaces;
using survey.Model;

namespace survey.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[Controller]")]
    [EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
    public class SurveyResponsesController : Controller
    {
        public ISurveyResponseRepository _surveyResponseRepository;

        public SurveyResponsesController(ISurveyResponseRepository surveyResponseRepository)
        {
            _surveyResponseRepository = surveyResponseRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<SurveyResponse>> Get()
        {
            return await _surveyResponseRepository.GetResponses();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetById")]
        public async Task<SurveyResponse> GetById(int id)
        {
            return await _surveyResponseRepository.GetResponseById(id);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] SurveyResponse response)
        {
            try
            {
                await _surveyResponseRepository.AddResponse(response);
                return CreatedAtRoute("GetById", new { id = response.responseId }, response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a breakpoint in the controller code, and it never hits. It's not a CORS issue, as I have the "EnableCors" controller atrribute.

I have tested the api using Postman, and it is able to hit the controller just fine. Just won't work when called from the client side of the application in VS 2017. Any ideas as to why I won't see the request reaching the controller/action?

Thanks.

Comment: If you use httpClient NOT use JSON.stringfy (else you must use httpClient). Your attribute [EnabledCors] say that it's allowed in the case you are indicated. If you want to be sure that there are no problem try first using [DisableCors] -after, you enable CORS-, se https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Have you subscribed to the angular method somewhere because it won't get executed until you subscribe to it.

Comment: Thank you Jai. I wasn't subscribing to the service request in the component. I added that and looks like it is hitting the controller now, although complaining of other issues. I will troubleshoot those. Not sure how to flag your comment as the accepted solution?